# display combox java in different JPanel

Tags: java, swing

How I can display the same JCombox in different JPanel.

In my code it displays just in the last JPanel.

```
for (int i=1; i<=nb_client; i++) {
    JPanel panel=new JPanel();
    String titre="client"+i;
    tabbedPane.add(titre, panel);
    combox.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 20));
    panel.add(combox);
    tabbedPane.validate();      
}
```

Comment: *"how i can display the same Jcombox in diffrent Jpanel.."* Why would you want to? See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Answer (score 2):

> how i can display the same Jcombox in diffrent Jpanel in my code it displays just in the last Jpanel

You can't.

A component can only have a single parent, so it will only ever display in the last panel you add the combo box to.

However you can share the model of the combo box:

```
JComboBox comboBox1 = new JComboBox(...);
JComboBox comboBox2 = new JComboBox( comboBox1.getModel() );
```

Now when you select an item in one it will also be selected in the other.

If you don't want this behaviour then you need to copy the data from one combo box to the other. So in this case you will need to write a loop. I'll let you write the loop to copy the data.